# Finding the intersection of 2 vectors algorithm critique/explanation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I have 2 vectors in cpp: [1,2,2,1] and [2,2]. I want the intersection to be: [2,2]. Here is my algorithm that I implemented but I get a heap overflow, I am not sure why. Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> intersect(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        //This is the intersection we will return
        vector<int> out;
        //If either array's are empty the intersection is empty
        if(nums1.size() == 0 || nums2.size() == 0) return out;
        //Iterate through first array, then go through each element of second array. After the end of each iteration we pop_front of first array. (Change to while loop)
        for(int i = 0; i &lt nums1.size(); nums1.erase(nums1.begin())){
            //flag to break out of second array iteration
            bool flag = false;
            int j = 0;
            while (!flag){
                if(nums1[i] == nums2[j]){
                    //Append the answer to the output. Doesn't matter if it is from array 1 or 2 they are equal
                    out.push_back(nums1[i]);
                    //I want to erase the element in the second array that was matched in the first array to insure that no integer is matched in the next iteration of the first array. (Heap buffer overflow??)
                    nums2.erase(nums2.begin()+j);
                    //If a match was found we break out of the second array iteration
                    flag = true;
                }
                //Check if index j is out of bounds, if it is we have reached the end of the second array
                if(j == nums2.size() - 1){
                    flag = true;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

I want to know why I can't erase the element in the second array that is matched with an element in the first array.

Comment: Two calls to `std::sort` and one call to `std::set_intersection` is all you need -- basically 3 lines of code.  There is no need for all of the code you have now.

Comment: Context: https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays-ii/description/

Comment: As an aside, you may want to pass in a copy of `nums2` rather than a reference. Otherwise, your deletions will affect the original, something that's likely to annoy the caller to no end :-) And, any time you pass in a reference for efficiency that you *don't* want to change (i.e., `nums1`), it should be `const`.

Comment: The method header is provided by Leetcode.

Comment: The problem with these questions that come from LeetCode is that the solution that will actually work looks nothing like the attempt made by the poster.  This is one example of this.  So should an actual answer to the question be posted here?  Also, this solution posted is not efficient if the arrays are large.

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e458ad8758b47b54).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey Paul I just moved one line of code and it worked! Also I didn't really want any optimization here. I just wanted to see if someone could explain to me why I was getting a heap buffer overflow.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul thanks for your answer I think that would be an optimal solution however I am really doing these leetcode problems to help me prepare for a technical interview test so I think by using std::set_intersection that is cheating because I am supposed to be implementing my own version of this function.

Comment: Many folks on LC seem convinced that if you use a builtin abstraction, you're "cheating". If I was hiring a developer, I'd rather hire one that knows how to use libraries when appropriate instead of rolling their own (usually slow and buggy) reimplementations. Also, where do you draw the line? C++ is already a high-level language with high-level abstractions like `vector`. The idea is that `vector` is allowed while `set_intersection` isn't strikes me as cherry-picking. IRL you'd never reimplement either and they basically exist at roughly the same level of abstraction.

Comment: @ggorlen I agree everyone should use c-style arrays!

Comment: @MatthewPecko [Look at the implementation for set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).  You do not see any calls to `erase`.  The point being made is that regardless of how short that code is that I linked to in the previous comment, did you know that was an answer?  If you didn't, then that's the point -- learning *how* to use the tools given to you.  Instead of showing how to build a table, your attempt is trying to show how to build a hammer, saw, screwdriver, etc.

Comment: @MatthewPecko I hope you're being sarcastic... If you're being serious, then C-style arrays are also a high level construct and you're stuck proving you're a "real" programmer by doing everything in assembly. Of course, then that's still high level and you're stuck writing machine code. The point is, go ahead and use the features the language gives you instead of throwing up imaginary walls.

Comment: @MatthewPecko -- If you were asked on an interview this question, you have to be very careful how you answer it.  Maybe the interviewer is looking to see if you know your C++ algorithms, and trying to write code from scratch like you're doing is a noble effort, but wrong for what the interviewer is looking for.  This is where LeetCode and similar sites are not helpful in this sense -- yes, you learn the underlying "how this solution works", but not also mentioning that there exists functions or set of functions that you can use may be a negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nums2` becomes empty before `nums1` does, your program exhibits undefined behavior by accessing `nums2[0]`. an index out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Can't believe I didn't see that. I moved the line where I checked if either array is empty to be inside the for loop (I'm sure that slowed it down a bit) But at least it gives me the right answer!!